# Printing Data from SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, string, echo

so I got some data from two queries, but I fail so bad in styling them.

```
echo '<div class="'.'col s6">'.'<h4><a href="'.'/topic.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</h4>'.'<img src="'.$row['image'].'".'class="'.'responsive-img">'.'<p class="'.'class="light'.'">'.$row['highlights'].'</p></a> '.'in '.$cat['name'].'</div>';
```

All I want is just to echo and style the data I got from the queries and include their href links. 
Code messes up when i try to add href="" and class="" because the "" corrupt the strings.

Is there any way to echo the data without messing things so bad?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting data from database? Your printing way is  incorrect in above code.

Comment: Why is my code incorrect?  It is just fine, but it fails when it has to do with href and class. In every other case it works perfectly.

-Edit: Prints data perfectly - Fails to style data in the way I want

Comment: This part seems wrong: `'].'".\'class="'.'respons`. I think you have 1 too many `'`s.

Comment: Also, why do you break out the string so much? I think it would be easier to read if you kept the hard-coded parts together.

Comment: @HikmatSijapati Sorry mate,you were right I did a mistake when I pasted the code. @Terminus Yep thats my problem, I am trying to get rid of these ` ' `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making life hard for yourself by trying to jam all of this into a single string. If most of what you are writing is HTML then it's usually best to write it outside of PHP tags and sprinkle the PHP in where you need it.

So rather than:

```
echo '<div class="'.'col s6">'.'<h4><a href="'.'/topic.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</h4>'.'<img src="'.$row['image'].'".\'class="'.'responsive-img">'.'<p class="'.'class="light'.'">'.$row['highlights'].'</p></a> '.'in '.$cat['name'].'</div>';
```

You could write it like so:

```
?>
<div class="col s6">
    <h4>
        <a href="/topic.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>">
            <?= $row['title'] ?>
            <img src="<?= $row['image'] ?>"class="responsive-img">
            <p class="light">
                <?= $row['highlights'] ?>
            </p>
        </a>in <?= $cat['name'] ?>
    </h4>
</div>
```

Writing like this will make it a lot easier to spot mistakes, you closed your `<h4>` in the wrong place, and also make it more readable to other people.

Comment: Ahm I got this echo on a function actualy, thats why I couldnt write my code like this.. You were right, just got in PHP and I dont have enough experience to deal through these situations. Thanks mate really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) method to render a template with the given variables, like this you provide better visibility on what is required and what will be the expected result.

so given your $row and $cat arrays are something like

```
$row = [
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Some title',
    'image' => 'http://something.test/some/image.png',
    'highlights' => 'Dont know what it might be',
];

$cat = [
    'name' => 'category one'
];
```

the following demonstrate how to inject their values into a given PHP template

```
<?PHP

$template = '
<div class="col s6">
    <a href="%s">
        <h4>%s</h4>
            <img src="%s" class="responsive-img">           
            <p class="light">%s</p>
    </a>in %s
</div>';

$rendered = sprintf(
    $template,
    'topic.php?id=' . $row['id'],
    $row['title'],
    $row['image'],
    $row['highlights'],
    $cat['name']
);

echo $rendered;
```

So the above example will output the following HTML snippet

```
<div class="col s6">
    <a href="topic.php?id=1">
        <h4>Some title</h4>
            <img src="http://something.test/some/image.png" class="responsive-img">           
            <p class="light">Dont know what it might be</p>
    </a>in category one
</div>
```

please note, your HTML itself has some flaws but seeing your question is about the PHP side I'm not going to get into the detail on that.

Comment: Thanks pal, really appreciated! I will try this method!

Answer (score 0):

You're doing unnecessary concatenations in some places. Also, you need to fix the position of `<h4>` tag as well.

```
echo '<div class="col s6"><a href="/topic.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><h4>'.$row['title'].'</h4><img src="'.$row['image'].'" class="responsive-img" /><p class="light">'.$row['highlights'].'</p></a> in '.$cat['name'].'</div>';
```

Comment: @GeorgeChareas Glad I could help. *Cheers! ;-)*